# R: How to find the lift of an itemset?

Tags: r, apriori

I have a transaction dataset with with A-Z items. Now I need to find the lift of the itemset: {A, B}. How should I approach in R?

Comment: Can you please provide some sample data using `dput()` and the desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lift is only defined on association rules. See https://michael.hahsler.net/research/association_rules/measures.html#lift

There is an "undocumented" implementation of lift for itemsets in the package `arules` in function `interestMeasure()`. It is defined as

```
lift(X) = support(X) / product_(i in X) support(i)
```

The support of the itemset over the product of the support of all items in the itemset. **Note:** This is not a standard definition!

Comment: Mr. Michael, 

Thank you for writing in. Appreciate. Truth to be told, I have found the idea from your paper only and put that into a function:

lift <- function(n, nA, nB, nAB) {(nAB/n)/(nA/n*nB/n)}

Comment: Great! interestMeasure() will also calculate this.